# jQuery - Horizontal Page Slide - EXAMPLE INCLUDED

Tags: jquery

Is anyone aware of a page slider that can take a whole div and slide it in from the left for example? Just a thought and I'm not good with jQuery (Hope to change that)

Thank you for anyone who has any  suggestions, Necro

---

EDIT:

[Example Here](http://www.aivahthemes.com/themes/gracious/) That should help you guys :D The bottom part of the page.

Comment: I just noticed that, I normally do...I'll go back to all my answered questions and see.

Answer (score 3):

I made an example for other question. Updated that to give you simple idea how to do that. Trick lies in CSS property 'margin-left'. Check the solution live at:

http://jsfiddle.net/pXy2C/1/

Comment: Perfect...Thanks a bunch. Just to clarify though, I just need to figure out how to make it slide in automatically on page load hidden from the left, into the middle of the page.